# turtle.numinput will not start in inputfield while turtle.textiput does

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I'm writing a small textbase game in Python.
When using the turtle functions numinput and textinput a textfield appears to ask for userinput.
When the textinputfield appears, you can start typing withouth needing to click in the input field, but with the numinputfield you need to click the field first.

I've tried adjusting the default value to empty and removing the statement alltogether, but that didn't work.

Comment: Please provide your code as a [mcve] and share which version of Python and OS you're using. Thanks!

Comment: @ggorlen:

I'm working on windows 11 with python 3.11

It boyles down to the following:

import turtle
x = turtle.textinput('Direction', 'N, E, S, W or X to mark the spot').upper()
x = turtle.numinput('Steps', 'How many paces' , minval=1, maxval=height*50)
turtle.hideturtle() # Hide the drawing tool
turtle.exitonclick() # Wait for user to end program

Comment: Thanks for the details. You can [edit] your post with that code so it's easier to read. Nonetheless, I'm not able to reproduce the problem on Ubuntu 22.04 with Py 3.10.12 using that code. I'll try it on Windows next time I'm on one (or someone else can if they beat me to it).

Answer (score 0):

I've written a small program to test the behavior you describe.  I can't reproduce your results.  Clicking on either the red circle or green square puts up a dialog box ready to take input:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def test_number(x, y):
    n = screen.numinput("Number Test", "Enter a number")
    writer.clear()
    writer.write(n, align='center', font=('Arial', 18, 'normal'))

def test_text(x, y):
    t = screen.textinput("Text Test", "Enter some text")
    writer.clear()
    writer.write(t, align='center', font=('Arial', 18, 'normal'))

screen = Screen()

writer = Turtle()
writer.hideturtle()

number_button = Turtle()
number_button.shape('circle')
number_button.color('red')
number_button.penup()
number_button.setx(200)
number_button.onclick(test_number)

text_button = Turtle()
text_button.shape('square')
text_button.color('green')
text_button.penup()
text_button.setx(-200)
text_button.onclick(test_text)

screen.mainloop()
```

Try this on your system and let us know if it behaves similarly to your program or not.  If this behaves on your system, and your code doesn't, I might suspect some odd use of `screen.listener()` in a loop, event or timer.  Which is why it's important to include your code with your question!

Comment: Nice work!
You test works like I would like it to work.

I didn't include the code because I figured it was 'just a regular commandline'.
Like I said, the textfield works, the numeric does not.
The block of code for the numeric part is:

def turtle_plot_steps():
    x = turtle.numinput('Steps', 'How many paces' , default=' ', minval=1, maxval=height*50)
    turtle_plot_steps.x = x

Comment: The `default=' '` (space character) doesn't make sense for `numinput()`, better to just leave it out.  The assignment to `x` property of symbol `turtle_plot_steps`, a function name, seems suspect.  Is `turtle_plot_steps()` invoked as an `onclick` handler?  If so, you'll need the `x` and `y` arguments, but python should have complained if that's the case.

Comment: I used the default=' ' to test, I also tried removing the default statement alltogether. It is not invoked as an onclick. the function.x is used to take the value out of the function for later use and it does not mess up the textinput.